# NPL technique to identify topics from Large text

Tags: nlp, data-mining, topic-modeling

What technique/algorithm would be suitable to identify the context/topic of various large text documents using NLP?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot out there, I suggest starting with IBM's Watson